# Multiple version of texlive installed how to remove the older version?

Tags: 18.04, texlive

I am having trouble figuring out how to remove older version of texlive on my laptop. Following is the output of some of the terminal command that might help in answering this question:

1. `/usr/bin/tex --version` outputs `TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
   kpathsea version 6.2.3 Copyright 2017 D.E. Knuth.`
2. `/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux/tex --version` outputs `TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2018)
   kpathsea version 6.3.0 Copyright 2018 D.E. Knuth.`

I want to remove Tex Live 2017. How can I do that?

Comment: How they were both installed could impact how to remove it.  You normally remove using the opposite command to how it was installed (ie. `sudo apt remove` if installed with `sudo apt install`).  If they were both installed that way; you specify a version; however how did you install them, esp. the later release. This will impact the method of removal for the older version.

Comment: @guiverc thanks for the hint, I had installed the older version via apt, and `sudo apt autoremove texlive-base texlive-binaries` fixed the issue